# Delete or edit Distribution List Outlook(contact Group)

Tags: c#

I need to delete a specific group of contacts in outlook.

I found some commands to add a new group in C#, but now I need to delete a group.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve. In this function below, I delete group named "Example" in my default contacts folder.

```
    private void RemoveItemGroup()
    {
        Outlook._Application outlookObj = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)
                      outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

        foreach (var curr in folder.Items.OfType<DistListItem>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(curr.DLName);
            if (curr.DLName == "Example")
            {
                curr.Delete();
            }

        }
    }
```